# why video view rotate automatically when using front camera?

Tags: android, video, camera

I did not understand this problem, when i record a video through back camera then video view showing actually view which should showing in the video View but when i use front camera then its rotate to opposite. i am using one class for both then why i am getting this type behavior of video view?

video view code

```
public class VideoPreviewActivity extends Activity  {
    VideoView VideoPreview;
    String videoURI ="VIDEO";
    Button back;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_preview_screen);
        VideoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_preview);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        videoURI = bundle.getString("VIDEO");
        PlayVideo();
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(VideoPreviewActivity.this, PicRecordShareActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    private void PlayVideo()
    {
        try
        {
            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(VideoPreviewActivity.this);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(VideoPreview);


            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video:\t"+videoIndex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Uri video = Uri.parse(videoURI);
            VideoPreview.setMediaController(mediaController);

            VideoPreview.setVideoURI(video);
            VideoPreview.requestFocus();
            VideoPreview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
            {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    VideoPreview.start();
                }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.toString());
            finish();
        }

    }


}
```

Thank You

Comment: The front camera is rotated by 90/180/270 degrees depending on the vendor. You need to check it's rotation first.

Comment: @Shark Please Look at my editable Code..